# Is it possible to change an objects constructor values after they have already been defined?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

In javascript, suppose I have made some class like this:

```
class Player {

  constructor(playerName, playerScore, playerTurn) {

    this.playerName = playerName;
    this.playerScore = playerScore;
    this.playerTurn = playerTurn;

  }

}
```

Then I create a player:

```
playerOne = new Player('Bob',0,false);
```

Is it possible to change playerOne's constructor information somehow? For example, suppose I want to change 'Bob' to 'Alice', but not create a new object. Is this possible?

Comment: `playerOne.playerName = "something";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the constructor is done, it's just an ordinary object, you can read and assign the properties normally.

```
playerOne.playerName = "Alice";
```